# Cannot read property undefined, typescript assigning class array issue

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is the code:

```
interface Statistics {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  symbol: string;
  rank: string;
}
class Coin {
  private _stats: Array < Statistics > ;

  constructor() {
    this._stats = new Array < Statistics > ();
  }

  set Stats(val: Array < Statistics > ) {
    this._stats = val;
  }

  get Stats() {
    return this._stats;
  }
}

let test: Array < Coin > = new Array < Coin > ();

test[0].Stats = results; // results is an array of type stats

console.log(test[0].Stats);
```

When I try to assign the result to test[0].Stats there is an error thrown:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Stats' of undefined

What is the issue here? From the looks of it I have correctly allocated the Array of Coin class?

Comment: The array is fine, there are no `Coin` in the array though

Comment: `test[0]` is `null` or `undefined` - `null.Stats` will result in an error. You need something at the first index - such as `test[0] = {};`

Comment: add a new Coin to the test array before the assignment statement

Comment: It's been a long day, thank you so much for the assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let test: Array < Coin > = new Array < Coin > ();` is just calling the constructor of `Array` and is not creating an instance of `Coin`.

Try `const test: Array < Coin > = [ new Coin() ];`

Comment: Thanks again, yeah I forgot the Coin assignment! Cheers